# Show/Hide Products on Category page on button click

Tags: magento2, category, product-list

**I want to show/hide the Product listing on Category page on button click.**

1. On my category page i am displaying one static block before products, this block contain one button.
2. My requirement is on click of that button i want to show/hide the Product listing which appears below, and not to be displayed by default 
   See Screenshot https://prnt.sc/qtze4v

Can i get the block name that shows product listing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for that

add an id on button (view details) like id="open_details", and on detail block add id like id="details" then add following script

```
<script>
  require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){  
     $('#open_details').click(function () {
        $('#details').slideToggle();
     }
  });
</script>
```

also add css

```
#details{display:none}
```

Comment: What is the name of the block? How to add id in block?

Comment: Here @waqar give you sample example, but you can own CSS ( ID or CLASS ) to section and change accordingly in above script

Comment: @ManishBhojwani the below section comes from different file. Is the logic above possible ?? if i write the script in one file to hide the div in another file?

Comment: i am not sure about your theme structure but it can be done by making changes in app/design/frontend/Magento/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml, file.

Comment: @Nafisa Yes, you can add the script in one file. No problem if div tag is in another file.